# Automatic installation of NVIDIA CUDA and NVIDIA drivers

Tags: nvidia, display

My system does not have an nVIDIA card installed on it, and neither did I execute any command to install the same.

However, the upgrade check lists the installation of the nvidia driver (331.113).

What is wrong in the configuration of my system?

Comment: Please open the terminal and check your graphics card name and chipset by running this command: `lspci -nn | grep VGA`.

Comment: Here is the result of the command: 

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:a011] (rev 02)`

Answer (score 0):

Your results of running the command `lspci -nn | grep VGA` are:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:a011] (rev 02)
```

Your OS has not detected an NVIDIA card installed on it, as you said in your question, and so you should uncheck the NVIDIA driver (331.113) from your upgrade checklist, because you don't need it. If you have already installed nvidia-331, you can also safely uninstall it.

If you have installed either libcudart5.5 or nvidia-cuda-toolkit, you can also safely uninstall them.

Comment: What is interesting is, even if I did uncheck the same, the update-manager still managed to install it. Therefore, I executed a `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` on the command line,

Comment: Take a look at this Launchpad bug report [automatic update of nvidia driver shows error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331-updates/+bug/1402145) -- Package: nvidia-331-updates 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4.

Answer (score -1):

You can list the drivers with the command

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Also double confirm nvidia driver with its settings

```
gksudo nvidia-settings
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers devices` can sometimes give misleading results. For example, if you mistakenly download and install the wrong proprietary graphics driver from the official AMD website or the official NVIDIA website, the command will sometimes report the installed graphics driver as recommended even when the driver is not working. As far as I know the command does return accurate results if the proprietary graphics driver came from one of the Ubuntu repos, so you have to uninstall whatever graphics driver that didn't come from the Ubuntu repos to be certain that you will get accurate results.

Comment: The question was to inquire, as to why were the nvidia-* drivers automatically selected for installation, if I did not have the required hardware!